# ASP App_Code classes not behaving as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net

Deploying a locally created website to a remote machine (first time I've done this) and I'm having an issue with my classes being read from the App_Code folder.

It works just fine on my local machine, but I get a compilation error on the remote machine.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'database' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The class's name is database, and if I delete the class calls from my default page it loads normally without the functionality that the class would bring of course.

The only difference that I can think of is my local machine is running .net 4.5 and the remote is 4.0. Maybe something needs to go in the web.config file? I'm really stumped and couldn't find anything relevant with what I was attempting to google.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's database a seperate class library? If so check that it is the same dot net version as the main project

Comment: you have to run it on .net 4.5 on the remove, too, or compile it with .net 4.0

Answer (score 2):

You got a parameter in the web.config telling wich framework to be the targetframework...

`<system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />`

Comment: It seems to be related to this, somehow this is missing in my web.config on the remote machine. When I added it in, it's telling me that targetFramework attribute doesn't exist.